# Difference between variables and expressions for ReplaceAll

Tags: simplifying-expressions, replacement, tensors, xact

I'm doing some GR calculations with xAct. I get an expression that is heavy. In order to simplify the results, I try to use the function `ReplaceAll` in simple cases. Here's an expression I want to simplify. The $R_{abcd}R^{abcd}$ is the one I want to replace. To make it simple, I put $1$:

[image]

```
ReplaceAll[perturb, 
 x_*RiemannCD[a, b, c, d] RiemannCD[-a, -b, -c, -d]*y_ -> 1]
```

where `perturb` is a variable containing the expression above. In its definition I used :

```
\[Delta]Sphi =  VarD[\[Phi][]][Lc + Lm] // ContractMetric;
perturb = Perturbation[\[Delta]Sphi, 0] // ExpandPerturbation // SortCovDs // ContractMetric
```

Here is the InputForm for `perturb`:

```
PD[-a][PD[a][\[Phi][]]] + PD[a][PD[-a][\[Phi][]]] - 
 4*\[Alpha]*RicciCD[-a, -b]*RicciCD[a, b]*
  Derivative[1][F][\[Phi][]] + \[Alpha]*RicciScalarCD[]^2*
  Derivative[1][F][\[Phi][]] + 
   \[Alpha]*RiemannCD[-a, -b, -c, -d]*RiemannCD[a, b, c, d]*
  Derivative[1][F][\[Phi][]] + 
 8*\[Beta]^3*RicciCD[-a, -b]*RicciCD[a, b]*\[Psi][]*
  Derivative[1][F][\[Phi][]] - 
   2*\[Beta]^3*RicciScalarCD[]^2*\[Psi][]*
  Derivative[1][F][\[Phi][]] - 
 2*\[Beta]^3*RiemannCD[-a, -b, -c, -d]*RiemannCD[a, b, c, d]*\[Psi][]*
  Derivative[1][F][\[Phi][]] + \[Beta]^3*\[Psi][]^2*
  Derivative[1][F][\[Phi][]]
```

Here is the problem:

- With `perturb`, the function gives me back the same expression, without any replacement.
- If instead I directly put the expression above, it perfectly works !

Can you explain what's going on and how I can to not to place everytime the whole expression ?

Thanks !

TrodaroX

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! Please edit the question and include the definition of `perturb` (copy and paste the `InputForm` from Mathematica) :)

Comment: Hmm, I guess I wasn't really clear. Copy the _output_ of the `perturb`, so that we can try the code ourself. `perturb = -2β^3 RiemannCD[...] ...`

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitely specify the lengths of factors in products, eg. the number of factors fact may be 0 to $\infty$

```
-2 \[Beta]^3 riemann1["\[Del]", a, b, c, d] riemann2["\[Del]", a, b, 
c, d] \[Psi] F'[\[Phi]] + \[Beta]^3 \[Psi]^2 F'[\[Phi]] /. {fact___*
riemann1["\[Del]", a, b, c, d] riemann2["\[Del]", a, b, c, d] :>Times[ fact]}
```

$$\beta ^3 \psi ^2 F'(\phi )-2 \beta ^3 \psi  F'(\phi )$$

Very important: Enclose fact in a Times, because the Pattern match yields a sequence of factors expanded in the outer Plus as a sum, not as a product.

Comment: Hey ! Thanks for your answer. When I try to execute `ReplaceAll[perturb,{fact___*
RiemannCD[-a, -b, -c, -d] RiemannCD[a, b, c, d] :>Times[ fact]}` this still gives me the unchanged expression. Even with `/.` notation.